# How can I open current session in new tab?

Tags: vue.js, jwt, session-cookies

When I open any link in my app in new tab I get on auth page. Other words current user session reset. I use JWT auth, my front-end developed on Vue.js. I've saved token in my cookies like this:

[image]

After hit any link in new tab (middle click or ctrl+click) I still have token in my cookie but I get on page auth:

[image]

How can I fix it? I need save current session during click link in new tab.
Why does it happen if my cookies have user token?

My auth mutations looks like:

```
    export const mTypes = {
    UPDATE_TOKEN: 'UPDATE_TOKEN',
    CLEAR_TOKEN: 'CLEAR_TOKEN',
    UPDATE_USER_INFO: 'UPDATE_USER_INFO',
    UPDATE_USER_STATUS: 'UPDATE_USER_STATUS',
};

export const mutations = {
    [mTypes.CLEAR_TOKEN](state) {
        state.username = null;
        toStorage(savingValues.token, 'remove');
    },

    [mTypes.UPDATE_TOKEN](state, token) {
        state.token = token.exp;
        toStorage(savingValues.token, token.exp);
    },

    [mTypes.UPDATE_USER_INFO](state, userInfo) {
        state.email = userInfo.email;
        state.id = userInfo.user_id;
        toStorage(savingValues.id, userInfo.user_id);
        state.username = userInfo.username;
        toStorage(savingValues.username, userInfo.username);
        toStorage(savingValues.token, userInfo.exp);
    },

    [mTypes.UPDATE_USER_STATUS](state, user) {
        state.isTeacher = user.type !== 's';
        toStorage(savingValues.isTeacher, state.isTeacher);

        state.isStaff = user.type === 'e';
        toStorage(savingValues.isStaff, state.isStaff);

        state.firstName = user.first_name;
        toStorage(savingValues.firstName, user.first_name);

        state.lastName = user.last_name;
        toStorage(savingValues.lastName, user.last_name);

    },
};
```

My actions auth looks like:

```
export const aTypes = {
    login: 'auth/login',
    logout: 'auth/logout',
    refresh: 'auth/refresh',
    updateUserStatus: 'auth/updateUserStatus',
    inspectToken: 'auth/inspectToken',
};

export const actions = {
    async login(cntx, {username, pswd, vm}) {
        /**
         * Logs in user: creates new token and saves personal user information
         * @param {string} username
         * @param {string} pswd
         * @param {Object} vm       Vue instance
         */
        try {
            dispatch(cntx, appActions.startLoading);

            let data = {};
            await api.login(username, pswd)
                .then(response => {
                    data = response.data;
                    vm.$connect();
                });
            cntx.commit(mutations.UPDATE_USER_INFO, jwt_decode(data.token));
            await dispatch(cntx, aTypes.updateUserStatus, vm);

            if (fromStorage('isStaff') === true) {
                await router.push('/Stat');
            } else {
                await router.push('/Dashboard');
            }
        } catch (e) {
            callErrorNotify(vm, vm.$t('loginError'), e, 5);
        } finally {
            dispatch(cntx, appActions.stopLoading);
        }
    },

    async updateUserStatus(cntx, {vm}) {
        /**
         * Gets and saves personal user information
         * @param {Object} vm       Vue instance
         */
        try {
            dispatch(cntx, appActions.startLoading);

            const {data} = await api.getFullUserInfo(cntx.getters.id);
            cntx.commit(mutations.UPDATE_USER_STATUS, data);

            if (localStorage.getItem(`tour_${data.id}_${data.username}`) === null) {
                initialTourSettings(data);
            }

            if (data.type === 't') {
                await dispatch(cntx, wsActions.createTeacherChannel);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            callErrorNotify(vm, vm.$t('loadError'), e, 5);
        } finally {
            dispatch(cntx, appActions.stopLoading);
        }
    },

    async logout(cntx, {vm}) {
        /**
         * Logs out user: delete its token from store and session storage.
         * @param {Object} vm       Vue instance
         */
        try {
            dispatch(cntx, appActions.startLoading);

            cntx.commit(mutations.CLEAR_TOKEN);
            if (cntx.state.isTeacher) {
                await dispatch(cntx, wsActions.closeTeacherChannel);
            }
            sessionStorage.clear();
            await router.push('/Auth').catch(err => {
                if (err.name !== 'NavigationDuplicated') {
                    console.log('Navigation duplicated: /Auth');
                }});
        } catch (e) {
            callErrorNotify(vm, vm.$t('logoutError'), e, 5);
        } finally {
            dispatch(cntx, appActions.stopLoading);
        }
    },

    async refresh(cntx, {token, vm}) {
        /**
         * Refreshes user token.
         * @param {string} token
         * @param {Object} vm       Vue instance
         */
        try {
            dispatch(cntx, appActions.startLoading);

            const {data} = await api.refresh(token);
            cntx.commit(mutations.UPDATE_TOKEN, jwt_decode(data.token));
            console.log('token was updated');
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            callErrorNotify(vm, vm.$t('tokenUpdateError'), e, 5);
            return false;
        } finally {
            dispatch(cntx, appActions.stopLoading);
        }
    },

    async inspectToken(cntx, {vm}) {
        /**
         * Checks whether it needed to update token every 30 minutes.
         * @param {Object} vm       Vue instance
         */
        try {
            let token = fromStorage(savingValues.token);
            if (!!token) {
                // 60s*50 = 3000s == 50 minutes
                const delta = new Date(token * 1000) - new Date();
                if (delta < 0) {
                    await dispatch(cntx, aTypes.logout, {vm});
                    return;
                }
                if (delta / 1000 <= 3000) {
                    await dispatch(cntx, aTypes.refresh, {token, vm});
                }
            } else {
                await dispatch(cntx, aTypes.logout, {vm});
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('error during inspectToken. ' + e);
            await dispatch(cntx, aTypes.logout, {vm});
        }
    },
};
```

And finally my component looks like this:

```
@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
    valid = false;
    username = '';
    pswd = '';

    get pswdRules() {
        return [
            (v) => !!v || this.$t('passwordRequired'),
        ]
    }

    get usernameRules() {
        return [
            (v) => !!v || this.$t('loginRequired'),
        ]
    }

    get isDarkTheme() {
        return this.$store.getters[appGetters.isDarkTheme];
    }

    get primary() {
        return colors.primary;
    }

    get neonBlue() {
        return colors.neonBlue;
    }

    get language() {
        return i18n.locale;
    }

    @Watch('language')
    onLanguageChanged(val) {
        this.$refs.form.resetValidation();
    }

    login() {
        if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
            this.$store.dispatch(
                authActions.login,
                {
                    username: this.username,
                    pswd: this.pswd,
                    vm: this
                }
            )
        }
    }

    mounted() {
        this.$disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check for that cookie before displaying the page. If you find the cookie, with an active session, then don't show the auth page.

Comment: @bassxzero How can I do it? Where I can find this file?

Comment: You need to post your home component and your auth component code or we can't help.

Comment: @bassxzero I did it above

Comment: and why are you storing in cookies use localstorage

Comment: @thatcoder I don't know actually I responsible for backend in this app, but now I need fix this in my frontend, I am beginner in Vue and front-end, help me to fix it.